# Formula for repayment profile

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, formula

Let's assume I have provided 12months (13 repayments in total, assuming first one is always zero) loan to my friend with quarterly repayment in (4/7/10/13).

Where deferred of 0/1/2/3 = payment in month 4 / deferred of 4/5/6 = payment in month 7, ..., deferred 10/11/12 = payment in month 13.

I’m trying to come up with the formula which would give me these (4/7/10/13) based on maturity/repayment interval and deferred provided.

Comment: Not quite sure what it is exactly what you're looking for, but have you looked into MOD function?

Comment: tried to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Still not quite sure if this is what you mean:
`=IF(ROWS(A$1:A1)-1=0;0;IF(MOD(ROWS(A$1:A1)-1;3)=0;1200/4;0))`
Where `1200` is to be replaced by the total sum of money.
This results in 1/3 of the total sum every 3 months, skipping month 0 (drag down formula).